# Is it possible to dynamically create functions/variables in a module?

Tags: python

Say, I have a general function `f(input, kind)` and a long list of `kind`. I would like to create functions `f_kind(input)` for each `kind` in the list. Instead of doing it manually by `f_kind1 = partial(f, kind=kind1)`, is it possible to create them more dynamically via a loop over the list (something similar to `setattr(class_name, method_name, method)` inside a class)?

Comment: Yes, but you are probably carefully constructing something that is very very difficult for anything other than you (and possibly in the future you Yourself when you unexpectedly come back to this code in a year or more and can’t remember why on earth the code is so complicated/incomprehensible) to maintain.

Comment: Of course, have you tried using partial in a loop?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean, how to actually do that? I don't seem to have access to something like `__dict__` inside the module itself.

Comment: You can use the `globals()` dict, but this is probably a bad idea

Comment: What do you mean? I meant it's a bad idea to dynamically generate these things.

Comment: OK, my bad. That does bind the name to the module. Then what is downside of it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminded by of an article I read long ago by Guido van Rossum  about implementing [multimethods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) in Python — because at it's core, that's what you're doing.

It would need to be adapted to work on a class, but I think it might be a better approach than using `setattr()` to achieve your goal.

**mm.py:**

```
''' MultiMethod module. '''

_registry = {}

class MultiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.typemap = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        types = tuple(arg.__class__ for arg in args)
        function = self.typemap.get(types)
        if function is None:
            raise TypeError("no match")
        return function(*args)

    def register(self, types, function):
        if types in self.typemap:
            raise TypeError("duplicate registration")
        print('registering: {!r} for args: {}'.format(function.__name__, types))
        self.typemap[types] = function

def multimethod(*types):
    def register(function):
        name = function.__name__
        mm = _registry.get(name)
        if mm is None:
            mm = _registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)
        mm.register(types, function)
        return mm

    return register
```

Sample usage.

**mm_test.py:**

```
from mm import multimethod

@multimethod(int)
def f(input):
    print('f_{}({!r}) called'.format(type(input).__name__, input))


@multimethod(str)
def f(input):
    print('f_{}({!r}) called'.format(type(input).__name__, input))

f('answer')
f(42)

@multimethod(float)
def f(input):
    print('f_{}({!r}) called'.format(type(input).__name__, input))

f(3.141529)
```

Output:

```
registering: 'f' for args: (<class 'int'>,)
registering: 'f' for args: (<class 'str'>,)
f_str('answer') called
f_int(42) called
registering: 'f' for args: (<class 'float'>,)
f_float(3.141529) called
```